# 'date' is an invalid value for the SoapElementAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a web service URL from my customer and its wsdl file.I added new project from wsdl file.

In wsdl

```
<element name="ProductionDate" type="xsd:date" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"/>
```

In reference.cs file

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute("ProductionDate", DataType="date",       IsNullable=true)]
public System.Nullable<System.DateTime> ProductionDate{
get {
  return this.ProductionDate;
}
set {
  this.ProductionDate= value;
}
}
```

When I try to create WebService class instance,it throw an exception :

> 'date' is an invalid value for the SoapElementAttribute.

I changed in my wsdl

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute("ProductionDate", DataType="date")]
public System.DateTime ProductionDate{
get {
  return this.ProductionDate;
}
set {
  this.ProductionDate= value;
}
}
```

So I can create webService class instance but when I call from my customer webservice Url, throw an exception :

> Method 'q1:blabla not implemented: method name or namespace not
>   recognized.

So is there any other way to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

i believe u have to use datatype as 'dateTime' in .cs file for date datatype in xsd schema file.

try this

```
SoapElement(DataType = "dateTime")
```